# Ampscript help needed for Custom Subscription Center

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am using the below script in subscription center... Every time when I unselect all categories/checkboxes such as news_u, trans_u, prom_u and cust_u the page takes me to the 107 instead of 220.

I am trying work around if someone unselect all categories/checkboxes then it should go to unsubscription page (id 220) but if one of them is checked then it should go to 107. But when i unselect everything or select one of them it's going to the 107. And I can see the values are also successfully updating in data extension on behalf of 107.

Any clue what's wrong here?

```
If RequestParameter("submitted") == "submitted" then  

if @news_u == 'False' and @trans_u == 'False' and @prom_u == 'False' and @cust_u == 'False' then

RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(220,'Email',@email,'Language',@lang,'Global_Unsub','True'))

else

UpdateData('Active_Subscriptions_Kay',1,'Email',@email,'News_Updates',@news_u,'Promotions_Events',@prom_u,'Transit_Tips',@trans_u,'Customer_Feedback',@cust_u,'Date_of_Change',SystemDateToLocalDate(NOW()),'Language',@lang_u,'Global_Unsub_Date','')

Redirect(CloudPagesURL(107,'Email',@email,'Language',@lang,'Global_Unsub',@unsub_check))

endif endif
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you’re missing `RequestParameter` for all your checkboxes - you’re not setting them anywhere in your script, that’s why they are neither interpreted as true nor false and the else condition is evaluated.

Depending on what they are called in the form, you need to get their values first before evaluating them:

```
If RequestParameter("submitted") == "submitted" then  

if RequestParameter("news_u") == 'False' and 
RequestParameter("trans_u") == 'False' and RequestParameter("prom_u") == 'False' and RequestParameter("cust_u")== 'False' then

RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(220,'Email',@email,'Language',@lang,'Global_Unsub','True'))

else

UpdateData('Active_Subscriptions_Kay',1,'Email',@email,'News_Updates',@news_u,'Promotions_Events',@prom_u,'Transit_Tips',@trans_u,'Customer_Feedback',@cust_u,'Date_of_Change',SystemDateToLocalDate(NOW()),'Language',@lang_u,'Global_Unsub_Date','')

Redirect(CloudPagesURL(107,'Email',@email,'Language',@lang,'Global_Unsub',@unsub_check))

endif endif
```

Ps. You didn’t include the form in your question, so it’s hard to guess what you have inside, but you’re using regular HTML checkboxes, they will evaluate to the vale `on` if checked, so you might have to use something like that:

`RequestParameter("news_u") != 'on'`

Here’s an article that, among other things, explains working with HTML forms and AMPscript: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2020/10/05/working-with-salesforce-multi-select-picklists-in-ampscript/